# python how to use a magic method to set a attribute to a class's method

Tags: python, methods, attributes

```
    class Foo(object):
        def static_var():
            def decorator(func):
                setattr(func, "different", "think different")
                return func
            return decorator
        @static_var()
        def think(self):
            pass
```

As you can see the codes above, when I type print Foo().think.different, the output will be "think different". But the question is I should use magic method to get this, how can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defining a decorator within a class seems a unnecessarily complex way to do:

```
class Foo(object):

    def think(self):
        pass

    setattr(think, "different", "think different")    



print(Foo().think.different)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `__getattr__()`, which is called when an undefined attribute is called. Or use `__getattribute__()`, which is called for all attributes.. when the required attribute is called, make it return the method. Here is I think what you need

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def printer(self,input):
        print(input)

    def __getattr__(self,atr):
        if atr == 'methd':
            return self.printer
```

Be careful to use `__getattribute__()` This might lead to infinite loop if you call the method using `self.attribute` inside `__getattribute__()`

Comment: Everything in python is an Object. So you can set an attribute to point to a class method.